# Python: decorate __call__ and ordinary function with the same decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

Is it possible in Python 2.6-2.7 to use the same decorator for the following task:

```
class ComplextCallableObject(object):
    @wrap_me
    def __call__(self, a1, a2):
        pass

@wrap_me
def simple_function(a1, a2):
    pass
```

Both `ComplextCallableObject.__call__` and `simple_function` has the same args, but `__call__` also has `self` for the first arg. In the `wrap_me` decorator I need an access for the function being wrapped args.

Comment: What is `wrap_me` supposed to accomplish? How is it that both functions perform a `wrap_me`-able task if they take different sorts of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the time of definition (the class block in this case), the code cannot tell how a function will be used except by naming convention.  Modifying your example a bit:

```
class ComplextCallableObject(object):
    @wrap_me
    def __call__(self, a1, a2):
        pass #...

@wrap_me
def simple_function(tgt, a1, a2):
    pass

ComplextCallableObject.anInstanceMethod = simple_function
ComplextCallableObject.anClassMethod = classmethod(simple_function)
ComplextCallableObject.aStaticMethod = staticmethod(simple_function)
```

In this case, `simple_function` is implementing a function taking a target and two parameters, an instance method taking two parameters, a class method taking two parameters, and a static method taking a target and two parameters.  But these uses are not bound until after the function is defined.  Both `staticmethod` and `classmethod` return a different object type, so you can tell those apart, if need be.

If you did want to use convention, you could inspect the function's first argument name to see if it is `self`:

```
def wrap_me(fn):
    names = fn.func_code.co_varnames
    if names and names[0]=='self':
        print 'looks like an instance method'
    else: print 'looks like a function'
    return fn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def wrap_me(*args):
    a1, a2 = args if len(args) == 2 else args[1:]
    ...
```

Of course, you will need to modify the returned function to take the `self` argument if `wrap_me` was called on a class method as well.

By the way, assuming you're not actually using `self` inside the function which you're decorating, it should really be a static method.

Comment: I use `self` in `__call__` (initialize heavy stuff in `__init__` and use it in `__call__`), when I don't use `self` in `__call__` I convert those objects into simple functions

Comment: So the "same" decorator is doing two different things, depending on whether it's called on a method or a function? Why not make two decorators?

Answer (score 0):

This may be pretty dumb, but might as well work for the simplest case:

```
In [1]: def wrap_me(func):
   ...:     def wrapped(*args):
   ...:         print 'arg1 is', args[-2]
   ...:         print 'arg2 is', args[-1]
   ...:         func(*args)
   ...:     return wrapped
   ...:
In [2]: class ComplexCallableObject(object):
   ...:     @wrap_me
   ...:     def __call__(self, a1, a2):
   ...:         print 'class object called'
   ...:
In [3]: @wrap_me
   ...: def simple_function(a1, a2):
   ...:     print 'function called'
   ...:
In [4]: simple_function('A', 'B')
arg1 is A
arg2 is B
function called
In [5]: o = ComplexCallableObject()
In [6]: o('A', 'B')
arg1 is A
arg2 is B
class object called
```

Comment: Oops, I've overlooked the answer by katrielalex, which is essentially the same. I'll let it hang here for illustration if no one minds.